# Replace AnimationDrawable by using jetPack Compose Image

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, android-jetpack-compose, android-drawable

I want to replace my view which I created in xml with the Jetpack Compose API.

But now I am stuck on replacing my AnimationDrawable.

I use it to make a "Charging Animation" by start a Transistion of 3 images (low battery, mid battery and full battery image)

So when phone is charging I start the animation by calling a TimerTask to start the Animation infinite until the phone is disconnected from power source.

```
private class MyTimerTask(private val transitionDrawable: AnimationDrawable) : TimerTask() {
    override fun run() {
        Dispatcher.runOnUiThread {
            transitionDrawable.start()
        }
    }
}

init {
    drawLow = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.mipmap.low_battery)
    drawMid = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.mipmap.mid_battery)
    drawFull = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.mipmap.full_battery)

    if (drawLow !== null && drawMid != null && drawFull != null) {
        mTransitionDrawable.addFrame(drawLow, 500)
        mTransitionDrawable.addFrame(drawMid, 500)
        mTransitionDrawable.addFrame(drawFull, 500)
    }
}
```

How do I do it with the compose API? I have to convert the png files to ImageBitmap. So I cannot use the AnimationDrawable anymore.

```
((ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.resources, R.mipmap.low_battery, context.theme) as BitmapDrawable).bitmap).asImageBitmap()
```

So what can I do to achieve the "charging animation"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1、**`build.gradle` Configure the `useSupportLibrary` property:

```
android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.your.package.xxxx"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }
}
```

**2、dependencies**：

```
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-drawablepainter:0.28.0"
```

**3、Display**:

```
val animationDrawable = AnimationDrawable()
//add your images in animationDrawable by giving information of duration etc like you gave in xml file..
Image(
    painter = rememberDrawablePainter(animationDrawable),
    contentDescription = null,
    modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize(), 
    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
)

animationDrawable?.start()
```

Comment: perfect :) 
In my case I use then a viewModel to change between animationDrawable and normal drawable in case phone is not charging. Thank you very much :)